# Ionic only works with ionic run android

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a weird issue with my ionic app, it only works when i run with : 'ionic run android' from my computer (testing) to my mobile. but when i want to run the app from my mobile it dont loads the database (i was using sqlite)

I put my code on onDeviceReady(), it is wrong? (im working without angular, only js and cordova):

```
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        //console.log('onload');
    }

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
       //my main code
    }
```

please, can you help me?

Comment: has your security settings (of android) setted properly? (accept 3rd not verified apk?)

Comment: Thanks Federico! Yes , it acceot 3rd not verified  apk, is really weird, what other thing you feel can break the app?

Comment: Try to Connecticut device with chrome debugger

Comment: Yes, im using Gapdebug

Comment: Are you sure you are not running it with the 'live' parameter on? becouse that needs to be plugged in to work

Comment: HI Hiraqui, thanks, please, can you tell more about it? Im not sure what you mean but surely is a good tip.

Comment: In emulator it is working and not on mobile ?? Can you check for console errors using chrome://inspect

Comment: hi, sorry delay, yes, i was using Gapdebug and it connect with chrome, when i run the first time, from computer (ionic run android), it works fine. than, from mobile it dont work.